# Unable to start node app with shell script

Tags: node.js, docker

I created an node.js Docker image.
Using `CMD node myapp.js` in the end of my `Dockerfile`, it starts.
But when I use `CMD /root/start.sh`, then it fails.

This is how my `start.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
node myapp.js
```

And here are the important lines of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:latest
COPY config/start.sh /root/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/start.sh
WORKDIR /my/app/directory

RUN apt-get install -y wget && \
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/node-v5.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v5.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
rm -f node-v5.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# works:
CMD node myapp.js

# doesn't work:
CMD /root/start.sh
```

Using `docker logs` I get: `standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`
But I don't understand, because if I add `RUN ls /root` in my Dockerfile, I can see the file exists.
I also tried with full paths in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/node /my/app/directory/myapp.js
```

but nothing changed. So what can be the problem?

Comment: What image are you basing the build on?

Comment: @Matt: I added some entries I use in my Dockerfile

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/node`?

Comment: or just run `docker run <yourimage> which node` to confirm

Comment: I updated my Dockerfile to `ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`. `docker run <yourimage> which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`. Still same error.

Comment: Try `docker run -entrypoint="/bin/bash" -i your_image
`? Maybe this article will be helpful: [gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile](http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/docker/gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile-en/). Also, I recommend using some base image like [pushion/baseimage](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/) to build your own image. It has a structured way for booting process.

Comment: It works: `entrypoint: /bin/bash` *and* `command: /root/start.sh` (using docker-compose) ... but I don't really understand why =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker run -entrypoint="/bin/bash" -i your_image`.

What you used is the *shell form* of [dockerfile CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). As described in the doc, the default shell binary is `/bin/sh`, not as your expected `/bin/bash` in `start.sh` line 1.

Or try using *exec form*, that is `CMD ["/root/start.sh"]`.

Comment: The `debian` image has bash installed so it can be used for a script.

Answer (score 1):

Most common error I've seen is creating the start.sh on a Windows system and saving the file either with a different character encoding or including windows linefeeds. The `/bin/bash^M` is not the same as `/bin/bash` but you won't see that linefeed on Windows. You also want to save the file in ascii encoding, not any of the multi-character UTF encodings.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, but that wasn't the problem. But maybe it has something to do with my next issue? When I use `sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER/$myvar/g" "/full/path/to/my/file.js"` with `RUN` inside my Dockerfile, it works. But using this line inside my `start.sh` script, I get an "no such file or directory" error. I don't understand, because I gave the full path.